# Question with a Javascript command in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a question regarding a javascript command. What I am doing is on a asp.net page, a user clicks on a print button which I have another page open up and at the bottom of that page, I put in a simple script command, but I have noticed that my window.close doesnt always work. Here is my code below. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
               window.print();
               window.close();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a delay before calling `window.close()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.print();
    setTimeout(window.close, 10000);
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry for saying this, but that is not a good solution, because it will have different effects in different browsers. In IE for example the "countdown" starts when the print-dialog closes, in Chrome immediately because Chrome doesn't open a modal dialog for printing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will get it to work this way. For example in IE the *print* function will prevent the *close* function and in many versions of Chrome window.close doesn't work.

There are 2 other ways of doing this:

1. If possible try to use a print style-sheet by specifying an own stylesheet with media="print". In this stylesheet you can hide things such as navigation menus and choose appropriate colors for printing. [details on selfhtml](http://aktuell.de.selfhtml.org/artikel/css/drucklayout/)
2. If that does not work let the user understand what you are doing: rename your current print-button to "print preview" and let the user close this window when he is done printing. I have seen many other websites do it this way too. You can still call window.print if you like.